# Sequelize is not working in Heroku, but works in local

Tags: node.js, sql-server, heroku, sequelize.js, tedious

I use **Sequelize** to connect to my **Amazon RDS SQL Server**. It's working good, without any problem when I run app in local by using **nodemon**. But when I deploy to **Heroku**, It always throws `AccessDeniedError [SequelizeAccessDeniedError]: Login failed for user 'myuser'`

**node version**

> ```
> PS C:\Windows\system32> node -v
> v14.3.0
> ```

**package.json**

> ```
> {
>    "dependencies": {
>        ...
>        "sequelize": "^6.3.5",
>        "tedious": "^9.2.1"
>        ...
>    }
> }
> ```

**database.js**

> ```
> const { DB, USER, PWD, HOST, DB_INSTANCE } = process.env;
>    
> return new Sequelize(DB, USER, PWD, {
>    host: HOST,
>    dialect: 'mssql',
>    dialectOptions: {
>        instanceName: DB_INSTANCE,
>        options: {
>            validateBulkLoadParameters: false
>        }
>    }
> });
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `username` and `password` credentials keys to your config. It may helps.